# What is the intended pronunciation of "gist" (as in gist.github.com)?

Tags: pronunciation

Until today I've always heard it pronounced "jist" (similar to "just" or "gin"), but I just heard someone pronounce it with the same g-sound as "gold" or "give". What's the intended pronunciation?

Answer (score 12):

"jist" is correct.

[Gist is an actual English word, you can look it up in  the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gist)

Comment: and it fits...you get the gist?

Comment: ...git the gist.

Comment: Even though “gist” is an actual English word, I somehow felt it to be a word play on the word “Git” that is manifested in pronunciation.